# Reshape axes in figure using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, subplot

I am using a method from a library that used matplotlib to generate figures.

I receive an array of axes:

```
[<matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes at 0x117a32a90>,
 <matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes at 0x117bb1d68>,
 <matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes at 0x10bae8390>,
 <matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes at 0x10bb0add8>,
 <matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes at 0x10c153898>,
 <matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes at 0x1159412e8>,
 <matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes at 0x115964d30>]
```

In the original figure, all axes are in the same row (see first figure and imagine having additional two axes on the right side). I would like to reshape (à la numpy) the figure in order to create a grid of axes (see second figure).

[image: a]

[image: b]

Is it possible?

### Update - What I tried

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22885327/41977), I tried to use GridSpec:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure()

axs = #get list of axes

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3,3)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        k = i+j*3
        if k < len(axs):
            axs[k].set_position(gs[k].get_position(fig))    
            fig.add_subplot(gs[k])
```

But it does not work, and I have not a complete grasp of GridSpec yet. The figure displays the right number of subplots, but the axes are not added.

Comment: [GridSpec](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) seems like the way to go.

Comment: @HarvIpan Thanks, but in the link you posted it seems there's not a solution for this problem.

Comment: I have an answered question here about changing the position of an existing axes instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881301

Comment: @RuthC I tried a modified version of your code (see updated question), but it does not work. Do you know why?

Comment: Remove the last line `fig.add_subplot(gs[k])` as it doesn't seem useful to add a new subplot at all. Apart always provide a [mcve] when asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are almost there.  Without knowing what your plotting function is, I just made a dummy one for illustration.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec


def dummy_plots():
    """
    Return a 1d array of dummy plots.
    """
    _, ax_arr = plt.subplots(1, 9)

    for ax in ax_arr.flat:
        ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])

    return ax_arr


axs = dummy_plots()
fig = plt.gcf()

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3,3)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        k = i+j*3
        if k < len(axs):
            axs[k].set_position(gs[k].get_position(fig))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It works, thanks. I'm still dealing with the colorbars, but I think that's minor.

Answer (score 3):

What I find easier in many scenarios is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
# make 1d for easier access
ax = np.ravel(ax)
for i in range(4):
    ax[i].plot([0,1], [0, 1], c=f"C{i}")
# reshape to initial dimensions
ax = np.reshape(ax, (2, 2))
```

[image]