# Adding a subplot to a figure produced by a function

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, statsmodels

I use the [irf](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.irf.IRAnalysis.plot.html) function of statsmodels to produce a plot. Then, I use `ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)` to add a subplot to that figure. The code looks like:

```
irf = results.irf()
fig = irf.plot( plot_stderr= False, impulse = columns[1], response = columns[0])

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)          

ax1.plot(df[columns].dropna().index, df[columns].dropna().iloc[:, 1], color='red')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='red')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis
ax2.plot(df[columns].dropna().index, df[columns].dropna().iloc[:, 0], color='blue')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='blue')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 10)
```

This produces:

[image]

**Problem**: as you can see, the lower plot (irf plot) is clipped off. When I add `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 10)`, I get:

[image]

This helps a bit but at the cost of reducing the size of the top subplot, which is undesirable.

**Question:** How can I get both subplots of equal size without any clippings. I wish I could start with `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)` and then pass ax1 to the irf.plot(). Then I could have control over both axes. But apparently there is no way to pass an ax to irf.plot(). it just creates its own figure. I would even be satisfied with creating the two figures separately and then joining them and saving them as one figure, if there is a way for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential problem here is that `irf.plot` is creating a figure with a single subplot on it (one row, one column). You then add a second subplot with `add_subplot(211)`, which is telling matplotlib to arrange it in the top row of a 2-row configuration. But the original subplot is not being altered, so part of it is hidden by the new subplot (`ax1`).

`irf.plot` doesn't appear to have any options to control this at the time of creation as far as I can see.

But what we can do is modify the subplot position using [`GridSpec`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html) after creation (e.g. like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22885327/588071)), before adding the new subplot.

For example, something like this might work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

irf = results.irf()
fig = irf.plot(plot_stderr=False, impulse=columns[1], response=columns[0])

# Change position of irf plot axes
ax_irf = fig.get_axes()[0]
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax_irf.set_position(gs[0, 0].get_position(fig))
ax_irf.set_subplotspec(gs[0, 0])  # this might be superfluous

# Now add second subplot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])          

ax1.plot(df[columns].dropna().index, df[columns].dropna().iloc[:, 1], color='red')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='red')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis
ax2.plot(df[columns].dropna().index, df[columns].dropna().iloc[:, 0], color='blue')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='blue')
```

Comment: Thank you. This does exactly what I wanted to do.