# change figure layout based on subplot shapes dynamically

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, figure

I am currently working on a visualization of some data in two subplots. The two sub plots contain the same x and y axis and both use equal aspects. I currently can choose whether to show them next to each other or above each other, but I want it to do this automatically based on the shape of the plots.
[Flat plot, in subplot(2 by 2) layout but needs to show 2 by 1 favourably](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRMpy.png)
[High plot, in subplot (2 by 2) layout should be 1 by 2 favourably](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTZL2.png)

The image in the pictures is just change by zoom in on the plot in specific shapes.

The shapes of both subplots are always the same.

I currently am using this code to shape the plots, the

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
pcd=np.random.rand(1000,2)*40
mdfig=plt.figure()
ax=mdfig.add_subplot(224)
ax.set_aspect('equal',adjustable='box')
ax.set_title("fine tuned")
axs=mdfig.add_subplot(221,sharex=ax,sharey=ax)
axs.set_aspect('equal',adjustable='box')
axs.set_title("original")
# ax.set_zlim([-1,10])
def on_change(val):
    ax.cla()
    axs.cla()
    ax.set_title("fine tuned")
    ax.axis('scaled')
    axs.set_title("original")
    axs.axis('scaled')
    ax.scatter(pcd[:,0],pcd[:,1],s=5,c='black',label="pointcloud",alpha=freq_slider.val)
    axs.scatter(pcd[:,0],pcd[:,1],s=5,c='black',label="pointcloud",alpha=freq_slider.val)

axfreq = mdfig.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
freq_slider = Slider(
    ax=axfreq,
    label='transparency pointcloud',
    valmin=0,
    valmax=1,
    valinit=0,
    valstep=0.01
)
freq_slider.on_changed(on_change)    
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use gridspec to change the position of your subplots after creation. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881301/changing-matplotlib-subplot-size-position-after-axes-creation) are some other solutions for your task.

I called `ax.get_xlim` and `ax.get_ylim` to calculate the range of the axes. If x spans are bigger range the axis is longer because of the equal aspect ratio and it set the plots in a column otherwise the plots are set as a row.

Here is how you can change your `on_change` method. The x range is calculated according to the provided value for testing purposes.

```
def on_change(val):
    ax.cla()
    axs.cla()
    ax.set_title("fine tuned")
    ax.axis('scaled')
    axs.set_title("original")
    axs.axis('scaled')

    # Dynamic axis range for testing
    ax.set_xlim((0, 90*val))

    # Calculate Range of axis (proportional to axis size
    # because of equal aspect range
    xlim = ax.get_xlim()
    xrange = abs(xlim[1] - xlim[0])

    ylim = ax.get_ylim()
    yrange = abs(ylim[1] - ylim[0])

    if xrange < yrange:
        # vertical plot
        gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
    else:
        # flat plot
        gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1)
    ax.set_position(gs[0].get_position(mdfig))
    axs.set_position(gs[1].get_position(mdfig))
    ax.scatter(pcd[:,0],pcd[:,1],s=5,c='black',label="pointcloud",alpha=freq_slider.val)
    axs.scatter(pcd[:,0],pcd[:,1],s=5,c='black',label="pointcloud",alpha=freq_slider.val)
```